# Linux 4.1.6 Radeon UVD Not Responding

Tags: linux, radeon, kms, drm

I've seen the same problem before version `3.19`, could not remember since when, but it seems to disappear on version `3.19`.

But when I compile version `4.1.6` using `3.19` config, the problem came back.
Here's the output from `dmesg`:

```
[    0.332130] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[    0.334342] [drm] radeon kernel modesetting enabled.
[    0.336556] fb: switching to radeondrmfb from EFI VGA
[    0.340578] [drm] initializing kernel modesetting (PALM 0x1002:0x9802 0x10CF:0x1679).
[    0.340724] [drm] register mmio base: 0xD1100000
[    0.340732] [drm] register mmio size: 262144
[    0.340934] [drm] Detected VRAM RAM=384M, BAR=256M
[    0.340941] [drm] RAM width 32bits DDR
[    0.341202] [drm] radeon: 384M of VRAM memory ready
[    0.341210] [drm] radeon: 1024M of GTT memory ready.
[    0.341247] [drm] Loading PALM Microcode
[    0.341261] [drm] Internal thermal controller without fan control
[    0.341339] [drm] Found smc ucode version: 0x00010200
[    0.341567] [drm] radeon: dpm initialized
[    0.341716] [drm] GART: num cpu pages 262144, num gpu pages 262144
[    0.353313] [drm] PCIE GART of 1024M enabled (table at 0x0000000000274000).
[    0.354488] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[    0.354495] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[    0.354680] [drm] radeon: irq initialized.
[    0.372169] [drm] ring test on 0 succeeded in 1 usecs
[    0.372195] [drm] ring test on 3 succeeded in 2 usecs
[    1.418089] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start] *ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
[    2.437896] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start] *ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
[    3.457637] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start] *ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
[    4.477512] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start] *ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
[    5.497297] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start] *ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
[    6.517037] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start] *ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
[    7.536914] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start] *ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
[    8.556654] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start] *ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
[    9.576469] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start] *ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
[   10.596278] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start] *ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
[   10.616285] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start] *ERROR* UVD not responding, giving up!!!
[   10.636465] [drm:evergreen_startup] *ERROR* radeon: error initializing UVD (-1).
[   10.637520] [drm] ib test on ring 0 succeeded in 0 usecs
[   10.637574] [drm] ib test on ring 3 succeeded in 0 usecs
[   10.691957] [drm] radeon atom DIG backlight initialized
[   10.691979] [drm] Radeon Display Connectors
[   10.691987] [drm] Connector 0:
[   10.691994] [drm]   LVDS-1
[   10.692001] [drm]   HPD1
[   10.692009] [drm]   DDC: 0x6430 0x6430 0x6434 0x6434 0x6438 0x6438 0x643c 0x643c
[   10.692020] [drm]   Encoders:
[   10.692026] [drm]     LCD1: INTERNAL_UNIPHY
[   10.692033] [drm] Connector 1:
[   10.692039] [drm]   HDMI-A-1
[   10.692045] [drm]   HPD2
[   10.692052] [drm]   DDC: 0x6440 0x6440 0x6444 0x6444 0x6448 0x6448 0x644c 0x644c
[   10.692062] [drm]   Encoders:
[   10.692068] [drm]     DFP1: INTERNAL_UNIPHY
[   10.692074] [drm] Connector 2:
[   10.692080] [drm]   VGA-1
[   10.692088] [drm]   DDC: 0x64d8 0x64d8 0x64dc 0x64dc 0x64e0 0x64e0 0x64e4 0x64e4
[   10.692098] [drm]   Encoders:
[   10.692104] [drm]     CRT1: INTERNAL_KLDSCP_DAC1
[   11.109655] [drm] fb mappable at 0xC0478000
[   11.109673] [drm] vram apper at 0xC0000000
[   11.109680] [drm] size 4325376
[   11.109687] [drm] fb depth is 24
[   11.109693] [drm]    pitch is 5632
[   11.110159] fbcon: radeondrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[   11.678885] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fb0: radeondrmfb frame buffer device
[   11.684179] [drm] Initialized radeon 2.42.0 20080528 for 0000:00:01.0 on minor 0
```

It may not harm anything, but I've got white screen for at least 2 seconds on boot, so it's quite annoying for me.

I'm using Radeon HD 6310 on AMD Vision Fujitsu Lifebook.

Anyone know how to solve this problem?